# команды WinRAR (SFX-модуля) - есть ли пауза\задержка?

Tags: winrar

Делаю инсталляцию на WinRAR в ней две строки Setup.
Одна на cmd-исполняемый файл.
Вторая на exe-исполняемый файл.
Вторая должна стартовать, когда cmd выполнит все свои скрипты, но WinRar стартует вторую строку сразу после запуска первой.
Понятно, что можно реализовать запуск exe из cmd-файла, но ради личной любознательности хотелось бы уточнить - есть ли понятие паузы\задержки на выполнение (аналог консольной `start /wait`) в командах SFX WinRar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Боюсь, что [никак](http://www.win-rar.ru/testing/?COURSE_ID=1&LESSON_ID=18):

> Вместо названия приложения укажите имя BAT или CMD-файла, содержащего сценарий обработки содержимого SFX-архива. Сценарий, в свою очередь, может поочерёдно запускать несколько внешних приложений.

Максимум, что можно тут сделать - использовать вами же и предложенный подход - вызывать нужные приложения изнутри сценария, который будет указан в качестве Setup. (*прочие источники также рекомендуют делать этим способом*).